# BSOD Error codes

Tags: bsod, resources

Where is the best place to find out information about blue screen of death '`STOP`' and other error codes? [Technet has a list](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc952284.aspx) but it doesn't seem to have the `STOP` code that I've seen:

```
STOP 0x000000F4 (0x0000000000000003, 0xFFFFFA8070EFFC10,
                 0xFFFFFA8070EFFE48, 0xFFFFF800002108530)
```

I'm really after **general resources** on BSODs. Also is there any information on what the other values are?

Comment: Google had it .. http://www.google.com/search?q=0x000000F4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more searching I found this list on MSDN: ["Bug Check Codes"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789516.aspx)

Comment: The link above is old - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh406232.aspx is where I ended up eventually.

Answer (score 6):

The [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/install64bit.mspx) has `STOP` codes in its help file. Simply search for bug check and the error code, e.g. "bug check 0xf4". (Thanks Windows Internals)

Doesn't seem like the best option if you don't have it already installed.

Answer (score 2):

Despite being in German, [this list](http://www.bruchmann-web.de/de/support/windows/bluescreen/0x00000010/) is quite a nice cross-reference of BSOD codes to KB articles. Just remove the trailing /de from the KB URLs to change the language to English.

You can also search support.microsoft.com for ['stop' and the code](http://support.microsoft.com/search/default.aspx?query=stop+0x000000f4).

The values in brackets are parameters and their meaning differs depending on the STOP code. Frequently they don't provide much useful information. In this case, it [appears they may  refer to](http://forums.techarena.in/windows-server-help/673179.htm#post2524517):

1. The terminating object type
2. The terminating object
3. The process image file name
4. Pointer to an ASCII string containing an explanatory message

[This post](http://www.techsupportforum.com/microsoft-support/windows-xp-support/181457-stop-0x000000f4.html#post1080062) might also be useful in your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite places to look up errors is: [www.eventid.net](http://www.eventid.net)

They usually have a lot of good information about errors that occur.

-JFV